# Trying to cast setInstance.toArray() to Integer[], no compile time error but there is run time error, why?

Tags: java, casting, set, toarray

I'm experimenting with Java HashSet class and its toArray() method. Below is the code I have came up with. The compiler did not display any error but when I run the code, the IDE outputs the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;
    at JTOCollection.TheCollectionInterface.main(TheCollectionInterface.java:26)
Java Result: 1
```

Due to my inexperience, I can't fully understand the complete reason behind the error message, could someone please explain it to me?

```
Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>();
set1.add(1);
set1.add(2);
set1.add(3);
set1.add(2);

Integer[] intArray = (Integer[]) set1.toArray();
for(Integer i : intArray){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because you are using `public Object[] toArray()` instead of `public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)`.

use this:

```
Integer[] intArray =  set1.toArray(new Integer[set1.size()]);
```

docs for : `public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)`

> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this collection;
>   the runtime type of the returned array is that of the specified array.
>   If the collection fits in the specified array, it is returned therein.
>   Otherwise, a new array is allocated with the runtime type of the
>   specified array and the size of this collection.

Comment: Is the cast necessary?

Comment: @kirbyquerby oops just copied it from OP

Comment: What makes it faster is if the Integer array you pass into the method is the same length as set1, because resizing is no longer necessary. Using `Integer[] intArray =  set1.toArray(new Integer[set1.size()]);` will result in a minor improvement if you convert arrays often.

Comment: Yes, size the array properly.

Answer (score 2):

`set1.toArray()` is an Object[] and cannot be cast to an Integer[]. If you want to have an Integer[] try this:

```
Integer[] intArray = set1.toArray(new Integer[set1.size()]);
```

Comment: The reflective construction of an incorrectly sized array is pretty nasty. The idiom you should use is `set1.toArray(new Integer[set1.size()])`

Comment: @erickson Thank you for the improvement

Answer (score 0):

Method set1.toArray() return Object[], you need to explicitly cast every object in returned array to Integer. Below code will work for you.

```
Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>();
    set1.add(1);
    set1.add(2);
    set1.add(3);
    set1.add(2);

    Object[] intArray = set1.toArray();
    for(Object i : intArray){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```